# Deny IP by .htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having a lot o problems denying an IP that i would like to block from visiting my website. After a lot googling and and couple of trys i came to this that is almost working. And i mean almost because when i place the code all my website loses all the ccs.
Here is the code:

```
order allow,deny
deny from xxx.xxx.x.xxx
```

I tried a lot of version of this code - with the Allow ALL, switching the first part of the code to order deny,allow - and non of that really works. Only the one i posted before. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can deny an ip address using SetEnv and order directive.

```
SetEnvIf remote_addr ^xxx.xxx.x.xxx$ block=1
Order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from env=block
```

Comment: I just tried but it's still not working. I really don't understand thsi. I have some other website in wordpress and it works perfectly, but on this one has been a piece of work. Is it possible to be a problem of .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically says everything to deny:
1: on the first pass (on Allow) doesn't match anything.
2: the second pass (on Deny) gives one match (the one to deny)
3: and the third pass says that all not-matched requests are to be denied.

Try something like:

```
order deny,allow  
deny from 12.34.56.78  
deny from 78.56.34.12  
allow from all
```

The Order directive controls a controls a three-pass access control system 
[see Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html#order).

Ordering in Allow,Deny is done like this:
1: all Allow directives are evaluated; at least one must match, or the request is rejected.
2: all Deny directives are evaluated. If any matches, the request is rejected.
3:  any requests which do not match an Allow or a Deny directive are denied by default.

Comment: Still not working. Like i said, in another website i have, based on "wordpress", and this kind of code works perfectly. Could it be the file .htaccess or some rules that doens't allow me to use this code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this IP is not REMOTE_ADDR but another IP header such as HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR or HTTP_CLIENT_IP

See if this would do the job.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}                  ^12.34.56.78    [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}                     ^12.34.56.78    [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED}               ^12.34.56.78    [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}           ^12.34.56.78    [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}         ^12.34.56.78    [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION}        ^12.34.56.78    [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}       ^12.34.56.78    [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR}     ^12.34.56.78    [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP}          ^12.34.56.78
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```